# Powershell/MS Graph 365 Profile Picture update

Tags: powershell, office365, powershell-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I have a script I have been using to bulk update profile pictures within my organization.  It worked for well over 100 updates and now I am getting an error.  any help would be greatly appreciated.

Error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At C:\Users\mc\Documents - Information Technology\IT Documentation\Projects\Employee Photos\Processing\update-profile-pic.ps1:26 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $uri -InFile $AzUserImage -Headers ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Script:

```
connect-mggraph -scopes "User.ReadWrite.All","Group.ReadWrite.All"
Connect-AzAccount
$AzAppSecret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'xxxxxxxxxx' -Name 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -AsPlainText
$AzAppId     = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
$AzTenantId  = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
Set-Location -Path $PSScriptRoot
$tokenRequestBody = @{
        Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
        Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
        Client_Id     = $AzAppID
        Client_Secret = $AzAppSecret
    }
$tokenRequestUri = [String]::Format('https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token', $AzTenantId)
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenRequestUri -Method 'POST' -Body $tokenRequestBody -ErrorAction Stop
$accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token
$loc = "$PSScriptRoot\Pictures\"
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $loc -name)
{
$AzUserUPN = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
$AzUserImage = $loc + [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($file)
$uri = [String]::Format('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{0}/photo/$value', $AzUserUPN)
$Headers = @{
    'Authorization' = [String]::Format('Bearer {0}', $accessToken)
    'Content-Type'  = 'image/jpeg'
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $uri -InFile $AzUserImage -Headers $Headers
Move-Item -Path $loc\$file -Destination "$PSScriptRoot\completed"
}
```

Comment: When you say it worked for "over 100 updates," do you mean it worked 100 times in the past, but now doesn't work at all? Or do you mean it works for the first 100 users then fails for every attempt afterward? Also, do manual updates to the profile picture work?

Comment: It worked on several different occasions with varying amounts of users.  The first being the largest.  The following uses were small batches.  I've used it on 3-4 different occasions and now it no longer functions.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the issue. It's not a problem with the script. The image size is the problem. I'm not sure why they are different than what I have previously used, but resizing the images to an appropriate size allows me to update them.